# Download from google drive to aws ec2 server

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, download, google-drive-api

I have some images saved in google drive in following structure:

```
folder1:
 |
 |--sub_folder1
 | |
 | |-image1.jpg
 |  -image2.jpg
 |
 |--sub_folder2
    |
    |-image3.jpg
     -image4.jpg
```

I tried to download with gdown but it only download empty. I have made google drive link shareable with anyone also.

```
gdown https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/xxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxx
```

Comment: Download the file store it in memory then upload it.   use the drive API

Answer (score 0):

You can download from GoogleDrive with `gdown`.

```
gdown folder-id --folder
```

```
gdown https://drive.google.com/uc?id=FOLDER-ID --folder
```

Shared url will not work directly you need to copy id then you provided one of solution above.

`--folder` option is your need